# Open a process with Popen and kill after a time

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I want to kill a process after 5 minutes (ex), which I've opened with

```
subprocess.Popen()
p = subprocess.Popen('calc.exe', shell=True)  # example
```

I've printed the pip with `print(p.pid)`, slept for 10 seconds with `time.sleep(10)` , then killed the process with `p.kill()`.

The problem is that `calc.exe` is still running. I've used the `Process Explorer` to see what happens here and it seems that the subprocess will create a cmd with pid = `p.pid` which creates `calc.exe`, but with another pid which I don't know.

All code here:

```
import subprocess, os, time

p = subprocess.Popen('calc.exe', shell=True)

time.sleep(1)
print(p.pid)
p.kill()
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p.kill()` is killing the `cmd.exe` process that you're spawning with the `shell=True` option to `Popen`. That process is what `p.pid` refers to. Remove `shell=True` from your `Popen` statement, and it will kill `calc.exe` like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

i am not run program but it will work::

```
import subprocess
import time
p = subprocess.Popen(
['calc.exe'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()

time.sleep(1)
print (p.pid)
p.kill()
```

if it's work please let me know...